# Custom attribute for customer is not inserting data

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have written the install script to insert the attribute on admin form. But when i click save it does not save the value.
Below is the screen short. Prefer feel is the attribute.

[image]

Comment: have you added custom attribute to database?

Comment: You mean EAV which i wrote in installData.php file?

Comment: your attribute present in account section? And you are able to save from admin ?

Comment: No it's just displaying the field but not able to save it. It displays in form and not save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an attribute to customer EAV table, we have to use **'used_in_form'**  proper EAV implementation of customer attribute. Please check **InstallData.php** code where I have created customer attribute to insert company name.

```
<?php

namespace [Package_Name]\[Module_Name]\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_company', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Company',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_company')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create','customer_account_edit'],
            ]);

        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i did but its still not working

Comment: This should work, which version of magento you are using?

Comment: Magento 2.2.2 ver

Comment: This should work on version 2.2.2 as well. Now there is only one way I can check and i.e. to check your code. Is there a way you can show me your code?

Comment: I posted my code below

Comment: Can you please try above code, as I can see you have not used below code: 'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId, 'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId?

Comment: Is it important?

Comment: Yes it is important, the code that I have mentioned is working well. Can u please try my code and check?

Comment: Can you provide me some tutorials on magento 2?

Comment: I don’t have any tutorial as of now. We are using dev docs and refer core code. So you will have any question to ask, you can tag me in your questions and I will try to give solution as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $installer = $setup;
            $installer->startSetup();
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'prefer_feel', [
                        'type'         => 'varchar',
                        'label'        => 'Prefer Feel',
                        'input'        => 'text',
                        'required'     => false,
                        'visible'      => true,
                        'user_defined' => true,
                        'position'     => 999,
                        'system'       => 0,
                    'backend'  => '',
                    'source'   => '',
                    'default' => '',
                    'frontend' => '',
                    'unique'     => false,
                    'note'       => '',
    ]);


            $prefer_feel   = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "prefer_feel");

          $child1_firstname = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'prefer_feel');
          $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
          $used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
          $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
          $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
          $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
          $child1_firstname->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
              ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
              ->setData("is_system", 0)
              ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
              ->setData("is_visible", 1)
              ->setData("sort_order", 100);

          $child1_firstname->save();
          $installer->endSetup();


    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'prefer_feel')
        ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'adminhtml_checkout',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit'
        ]]);
    $attribute->save();

 }
```